# How to click on an google mail which has an certain link using serenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, gmail

So I do realize that using gmail api is the best solution, but due to the gmail account having restrictions (school) I can't actually use the api. So while I was searching for the solution I have found about selenium.
I haven't actually found a tutorial about how to filter emails/click on emails that is within 24 hours (which I think I can set it up myself) and click on emails with an link attached (google.meet)

Since the subject isn't always the same nor the sender, I can't actually limit it to the subject and email, so need help with some kind of email body filter.

```py
import webbrowser
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import email
import imaplib
import sys
import datetime
import smtplib

with open('accountdetail.txt', 'r') as file:
   for details in file:
       username,password = details.split(':')

# create a new Chrome session
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\driver\chromedriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()

# navigate to the application home page
driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/")

#get the username textbox
login_field = driver.find_element_by_name("identifier")
login_field.clear()

#enter username
login_field.send_keys(username)
login_field.send_keys(u'\ue007') #unicode for enter key
time.sleep(4)

#get the password textbox
password_field = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
password_field.clear()

#enter password
password_field.send_keys(password)
password_field.send_keys(u'\ue007') #unicode for enter key
time.sleep(10)

#navigate to gmail
driver.get("https://mail.google.com/")
```

I have found this resources, but for some reason they only work with subject and doesn't actually click on email with a link.
[How to click on a Particular email from gmail inbox in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198527/how-to-click-on-a-particular-email-from-gmail-inbox-in-selenium)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VJaWtz6kzs

Answer (score 0):

If you have the exact link, you can get the element using XPath and click:

```
url = r'YOUR URL, FROM ANY VARIABLE'
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="'+url+'"]').click()
```